# How to use data-image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

image is not displaying. i have side bar image in my app/assets/images/sidebar-4.jpg.but did not show.
tell me if there something wrong in my code.i am a beginner in ROR

```
dashboard.html.erb
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="black" data-image="/assets/sidebar-4.jpg"></div>
    my image https://imgur.com/a/QikMJJS
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want to show this image. Your code does not try to show any images.

Comment: Please check: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag